# is there a simpler version of ol.js file of openlayers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have tried to look for a simpler version of this file or a way to simplify it, but i haven´t succeed.

I´m building an app with rails 4 and when i want to push changes to heroku, first i precompile the assets manually with this instruction *RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile* but i get this error message *ExecJS::ProgramError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded* which is caused by ol.js file. I know this file is the problem because when i remove it from assets and execute the instruction again it works fine.

What should I do to get the assets precompiled?

Thanks!

Comment: I have deleted like 100 lines of the end of ol.js and now i can precompile assets without the error and still can see the map in develepment with the marker i had and the zoom in and out controls. The problem now is that in production i can´t see anything of these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's plenty of documentation which you can find by googling "openlayers custom build"](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html): follow it to create a custom build.

Comment: Thanks for replying, finally changed to openstreetmap with leaflet.js which worked perfectly fine for me.